# Why does Cordova's documentation page look similar to PhoneGap's documentation page?

Tags: cordova

[Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.4.0//index.html)
[PhoneGap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/index.html)

What template are they both using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure of the template, but Cordova and PhoneGap are essentially the same thing.

Cordova as we know it, was PhoneGap. Then Adobe bought PhoneGap and donated the code base to Apache and it became Apache Cordova. PhoneGap is now a fork of Cordova maintained by Adobe. They are almost identical, except that Adobe adds in their own 'flavor' with additions like `phonegap serve` for continuous updates and `phonegap remote build` for command line building through the PhoneGap Build service.

This is very much the same as when Oracle bought Mysql; leaving the main project open source and then maintaining their own fork of the project.