# Eclipse can't create project from existing code android

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I've created by command line a new phonegap application.When I try to get it by eclipse from android existing code it can't recognise as a android project.

Have I build my phonegap app before?

Phonegap project's folders are:

```
.cordova
hooks
merges
platforms
plugins
www
```

Comment: What is wrong in this answer?

Comment: Have you run `cordova platform add android` and then `cordova build`?

Comment: No.Must I?I've read a tutorial where told only to create a phonegap app by phonegap create @DawsonLoudon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`phonegap create [optional params]` will setup a blank project space. To add platforms to this project you must run `phonegap platform add [ios/android/wp8]`. Then depending on the platform and how you wish to develop it, you run either `phonegap prepare` or `phonegap build`.

In your case, since you wish to import to Eclipse, you will want to run:

```
phonegap platform add android
phonegap build
```

Then in Eclipse you can browse to `/PROJECT_PATH/platforms/android` and import your project.

Comment: I've used phonegap until now and cordova is not recognised from shell.

Comment: Sorry, I use `cordova`. updated all of the commands to use `phonegap`

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: Here is a recent explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569459/why-does-cordovas-documentation-page-look-similar-to-phonegaps-documentation-p/23570095#23570095

Comment: I've tried you command but:error platform add android is not a node

Comment: can you add the link to the tutorial that you are using to your question?

Comment: http://cleancodedevelopment-qualityseal.blogspot.nl/2012/11/how-to-install-phonegap-for-android.html

Comment: I would not use this as your base example as it is referencing `PhoneGap 2.2.0` the most current version is `PhoneGap 3.4.0`, try this one instead: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide