# what all the main differences in cordova and phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova

I have gone through many doccument. it shows like cordova is a power booster or somethink like that for the phonegap. Apart from that i need to know the differences at the time of implementation.

for example if we create a project in cmd for cordova it will be like,

```
 $ cordova create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"
    $ cd hello
    $ cordova platform add android
    $ cordova build
```

for phonegap it will be,

```
$ phonegap create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"
    $ cd hello
    $ phonegap platform add android
    $ phonegap build
```

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/blog/what-is-cordova-phonegap/

Comment: phonegap is a commercial product/service from adobe, cordova is an open source command line app from apache. both do the same thing, phonegap is supposed to be easier, but cordova's not bad.

Comment: see the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23569459/why-does-cordovas-documentation-page-look-similar-to-phonegaps-documentation-p/23570095#23570095

Comment: i need to know the the diiference in aspect of cmd commands.
like cordova create <foldername> <bundlename> <app name>,
phonegap create <foldername> <bundlename> <app name>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneGap is a distribution of Apache Cordova. You can think of Apache Cordova as the engine that powers PhoneGap, similar to how WebKit is the engine that powers Chrome or Safari. (Browser geeks, please allow me the affordance of this analogy and I’ll buy you a beer later.)

Over time, the PhoneGap distribution may contain additional tools that tie into other Adobe services, which would not be appropriate for an Apache project. For example, PhoneGap Build and Adobe Shadow together make a whole lot of strategic sense. PhoneGap will always remain free, open source software and will always be a free distribution of Apache Cordova.

Currently, the only difference is in the name of the download package and will remain so for some time.

Refer : http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what’s-in-a-name/